# Print custom module in a block

Tags: 8, blocks

I want to print a custom module in a type of content already created through the interface. Is there any way to print it?

I have seen that one of the ways in drupal 7 to print the module is by using the 'module_invoke' function, is there any equivalent in drupal 8 to print in a twig template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy Print's print.tpl.php file into module folder, and name it print--node--foo.tpl.php.

`function foo_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    $theme_registry['print__node__foo']['template'] = 'print--node--foo';
    $theme_registry['print__node__foo']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'foo');
}`

Note: My module and content type share the same name of foo.

Comment: @ SrMiguel if it works then accept my answer thanks!